# I want to send data with angular 4 to javaservlet (cross-domain)

Tags: java, angular, typescript, servlets, angular2-services

I want to send data form angular 4 to java servlet but I can't send because doesn't pass access control. I want to insert data to db with java servlet

[image]

this my code
front-end: data.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
 import { Headers, RequestOptions, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

 @Injectable()
 export class DataService {

 result: any;
 private url = '//localhost:8080/my-java-web/';
 constructor(private _http: Http) { }


 addBookWithPromise(user: object): Promise<object> {
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":" GET, POST, OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"});
  const options = new ResponseOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this._http.post(this.url + 'loginsuccess', user, 
   options).toPromise()
  .then(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
  const body = res.json();
   return body.data || {};
   }
   private handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
   return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
   }
   private handleErrorPromise (error: Response | any) {
   console.error(error.message || error);
   return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
   }

    }
```

backend: java servlet

```
public class LoginSuccess extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods"," GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");



    System.out.println("Success" +username);
```

Thank You Very Much

Comment: The backend code of the remote server the request is getting sent to must implement support for the CORS preflight OPTIONS request https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests. Just having it add the right response headers is often not enough—you must also ensure it sends the right response code, 200 or 204. To get more help, you should go into the Network pane of your browser devtools and reload and check the response shown there for the OPTIONS preflight the browser’s sending. In particular check the HTTP status code for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to read up on the CORS protocol.
I wrote a [blog post](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part1/) a while back about implementing CORS. It's based on the use of the Spring framework (specifically Spring Boot), not the Servlet API directly, but it does have a fairly extensive explanation of how CORS works.

Your specific problem is that you are only handling POSTs.
The CORS protocol involves the web browser making an OPTIONS request to your server.

It is this OPTIONS request that must have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and related headers returned in the response.

If the browser sees those headers in the response, it will then do the POST.

If it does not see those headers in the response to the OPTIONS request, you'll get an HTTP error, reading something like "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource", and the POST request will not be made.